# How to block while-loop till an action occur then continue

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, opencv, while-loop

I am retrieving frames form camera using opencv java library, and the as shown below in the code in the `while-loop`, as long as there is a grapped frame then execute the body of the `while-loop`. but what i want to do is, to implement a method that asks the user to press any key and when a key is pressed the next frame should be retrieved and the body of the while-loop exeutes till it reaches that method that asks for pressing a key and so on.

please let me know how can i achieve this.

**Code**:

```
while(vidCap.grab()) {
.....
.....
requestNextframe();//this method should block the while till a button is  
                   //pressed
.....
.....
}
```

Comment: Does wait() and notify() does not solve your problem?

Comment: @sunrise76 actually i have not tried them..i was thinking about implementing somthing like Listeners..but though i dont know how to implement it..but i will try ur suggestion

Comment: I think this design somehow "smells". The "UI should be in control". Meaning: your inner logic should not sit there and wait for a UI button to be pressed. Instead, when the UI button is pressed, that should trigger some "action". In your design, there is a "dependency" from the inner logic of your code ... to the outer UI. And in my eyes, that is the wrong direction!

Comment: @Jägermeister i need to to pause the while loop of the video cam so i can  change the view angle of the cam then continue

Comment: `waitKey(-1)` may do the trick

Comment: Are you building a UI ? If so why there is not button to do this?  You should not be worried about threading/wait/notify for a task such as this. @Jägermeister has put it clearly in his comments.